# “Unable to attach. The System cannot find the file specified” from Ripple and Android emulator in VS

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to build cardova project in VS while doing so i am getting a dialogue **"Unable to attach. The System cannot find the file specified"**  while trying to run the application in ripple emulator and also getting error in the console as "
**A required web socket component is missing. Please refer to the documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=403596.**"
I have installed VS in my system drive and also copied WebSocket4Net.dll file to its location C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows.
Please help to resolve this issue as after this android ripple emulator is getting opened in a separate browser which is very irritation as a developer to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just now. Running the file "vs2013mda_0.3.exe" (Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0) and selecting the "Repair" option fixed the "Unable to attach" issue for me.

Comment: I tried to Run "vs2013mda_0.3.exe"  but i am getting error message as setup blocked.The product version that you are trying to set up is earlier than the version already installed on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you must lunch the command from the root directory, c:\, changing the package GUID with your package GUID.

In my system:

```
C:\>"%ProgramData%\Package Cache\{dea88246-f74a-4171-ad6c-d9c978bf2973}\vs2013md
a_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43
fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760
```

To find the right package GUID I go to C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ and search for vs2013mda_0.1.exe and save the path in the block note, then change in path in the orignal command and lunch it from the root directory c:\, and its work.

Sorry fom my english. Goodbye!

Credits by netluke