# Visual studio hybrid app CTP4 debugging error

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I've just updated Visual Studio 2013 from *Update 3* to *Update 4* and Visual studio hybrid app from *CTP2* to *CTP3*. Compilation works just fine but debugging doesn't work.

The application start on the Android emulator, but debugging with HTML DOM doesn't work. I'm getting an error message:

```
Unable to attach, Cannot load sattelite assemblies containing cultured resources.
```

(*the original message is in French -- it says: `Impossible de s'attacher. Impossible de trouver ou de charger un assembly satellite attendu, contenant les ressources de secours ultimes pour une culture donnée` -- I'm not sure, if I translated it correctly to English*).

I'm getting this message since the update. I've already tried to reinstall Visual Studio and Cordova, but nothing changed. The error is present on other computer too.

Anyone has the same problem and knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I switch the language from german to english in both Windows and VS. But that don't solved the problem.

Than I found [this queston/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994994/unable-to-attach-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-from-ripple-and-an) . So I downloaded vs2013mda_0.3.exe again and did a repair.
For me it solved the problem.